# Airflow same dag runs notebook code at different times

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, airflow

New to airflow:
I need to run a notebook code from my application dag that's currently scheduled to run at 5AM PST for US region. But I want to expand to a few more countries and that notebook code needs to run at 5AM Local time for that given country.

E.g.

For UK, run the notebook at 5 AM UTC - while passing UK specific parameters to the notebook

For JP, run the notebook at 5 AM JST - while passing JP specific parameters to the notebook

Any ideas on how to do that? Can we pass multiple `schedule_interval`? Not sure how I'll associate parameters with each region's run tho in the same dag. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "5AM Local time for that given country" is a bit subtle,
as the UTC offset changes occasionally.
For example many places have a pair of one-hour DST shifts each year.
You mentioned "UTC" for UK,
but if you look at a Londoner's wristwatch
you will at times see it's an hour off from that.

> Can we pass multiple `schedule_interval`?

I imagine Airflow might be up to the task.
But it sounds a little hard, so here's my recommendation.

You have several source code files that you'd like to regularly run.
Associate a (non-numeric!) timezone string with each file,
e.g. `"Americas/Los_Angeles"`.

Run an Airflow task every hour, on the hour.
First it assigns `now` to be system time.
Next it scans those timezone strings,
converting `now` to the local timezone and extracting the current `hour`.
If `hour` is `5` then we run the associated code.

In your example, the task would actually run associated code 3 times
out of 24 executions. In the remaining 21 executions it would rapidly
perform a scan, find zero candidates ready, and immediately exit.

An advantage of this approach is it handles DST transitions properly,
using the current per-locale rules of each relevant city.

Comment: Correct, I'm passing the timezone for different countries, for US it's "Americas/Los_Angeles" (and using this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones for other countries, my "local time" wording is bad!)

I'm going to try your suggestion, and loop back - thank you so much!

Comment: So I eventually solved this by using DateTimeSensor in reschedule mode. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/sensors.html